# Not able to find the Rebuild option in Android Studio under Build Option

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 1.5.1 on windows 7 .I am not able to find the rebuild or clean option under the "Build" option?Is there any command to force rebuild or do it form the Android GUI?

[image]

The project was built in Eclipse and I have imported it in Android Studio.Earlier I was getting some error from google Play services which I have resolved by commenting the below line in the project.properties

target is android-23

```
android.library.reference.1=../../../../workspace/google-play-services_lib
```

Comment: Try this from the commandline using gradle wrapper. From the root directory of your project:

./gradlew clean

Comment: Have you restarted studio?

Comment: @jaydroider after importing the project there is no gradlew formed in the root of the app.

Comment: @I_Droid Yes I did !

Comment: I got it finally.I dont know the reason but i cloned my app repo again and imported the project (made in eclipse) .I can see the rebuild options now.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is something that you need to update before continuing to develop your project. Check on Help -> Check for Updates...

You should always keep Android Support Repository, Google Play Services, Google Repository, Android SDK Tools and Android SDK Platform-Tools updated.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem and my Android studio was also latest version. As a workaround for this problem what I did was to open the module settings and changed values and reverted back to old values and click ok. After that those missing menu items appeared.